# Experiencing memory errors while launching games, failing memtest

Tags: memory, motherboard, memtest, memory-error

I've been getting errors in Counter Strike: Global Offensive and Bioshock. CS:GO will sometimes fail when loading a map and the error contains "0xc0000005" For Bioshock this also will happen when trying to launch and it will contain the same error. I googled this for awhile and the consensus was to test the ram. So I fired up memtest today and tested all sticks, they failed at around 44% and the failing address was 129.0 MB. I figured this was going to happen so then I went about testing them individually in slot 1. They all failed at this exact point. I then tested one of the sticks in slot 4 and it failed at the same point. What can I draw from these conclusions? My computer seems to run fine except from the aforementioned errors, its not like I'm getting blue screens from memory errors, everything is failing gracefully. The memtest makes it look like a huge problem though but it doesn't make much sense to me. Could the motherboard possibly be bad?

I don't have any overclocking in place so all of my ram should be on stock settings.

Also the motherboard is a Gigabyte Z77X-UD5H

Comment: Memory can fail due to prblems with the CPU, the memory controller, the traces on the board, faulty DIMMs and wrong timing (and probably a few more which I forgot). Given that all four sticks fail at the same place is is a safe guess to assume the problem is not with these. To make sure you could test the RAM in a different board (I assume it will come out fine). The rest of the testing is a bit harder unless you got a spare CPU or a spare MB.

Comment: Do you have any idea what I could start to investigate next since this appears to not be the problem?

Comment: Without another motherboard or a spare CPU? That leaves only two things: A visual inspection or the board, looking for damage and 'loosening' the RAM timings. I do not expect either of the two to yield a result. Which basically leaves the option of RMA, esp. if you have a way to easily reproduce the problem.

Comment: Your suggesting a RMA of the motherboard right?

Comment: Dpends on where you bought it. If it is a package with both CPU and motherboard, then I suggest returning both to the shop for testing and repairing. If not I would expect the MB  to fail before the CPU, but that is just because I never had a CPU fail on me yet.